# Resque Job Stuck in pending state forever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I call this from the controller:

```
Resque.enqueue(SendUninstallFeedbackEmail, shop.id)
```

My worker:

```
require 'resque-retry'

class SendUninstallFeedbackEmail
    extend Resque::Plugins::Retry

    @queue = :uninstall_feedback_queue

    @retry_limit = 3
    @retry_delay = 60

    def self.perform(shop_id)
      shop = Shop.find(shop_id)
      NotificationMailer.uninstall_feedback(shop).deliver_now
    end

end
```

When I trigger `Resque.enqueue(SendUninstallFeedbackEmail, shop.id)` , the job is showing up in the resque UI under the correct queue, but it just stays as a "pending" state forever.

Here's my Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec rails s
redis: redis-server
worker: env QUEUE=* bundle exec rake environment resque:work
```

Where am I going wrong?